# Is the prepositional phrase an adverbial or adjective phrase

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, adverbs, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases

In the sentence quoted below are the prepositions "for 2021" and "without latest software" acting as an adjective or adverb?

> "Fossil announces new smartwatches for 2021 without latest software"

Comment: What parts of the sentence do you think those phrases modify? Does that help you answer your question?

Comment: I feel like the prepositional phrases could be modifying the nouns and the verb

Comment: Really? You think "without the latest hardware" might modify "announces"?

Comment: Anna, where did you find this sentence? Asking because the placement of words doesn't seem right.